# Forward SIP Domain Call to Elastic SIP Trunk

Tags: twilio

I'd like to allow SIP Domain registered phones to dial on prem extensions, and be connected through an Elastic Sip Trunk.

The idea being that remote workers can register their phones via Twilio, then be able to dial local extensions and reach people at the office.

Is it possible to connect the public domain and elastic sip trunk like that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the Twilio SIP Registered phones to dial via the E.164 phone numbers assigned to the Elastic SIP Trunk. A SIP Domain registered device cannot directly dial the Elastic SIP Trunk origination URI.

Another approach is to use Programmable Voice SIP to connect the second leg to the PBX, [Outbound - Receiving SIP from Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/receiving-sip). You can use the Studio [Connect Call To widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/connect-call) (via SIP) for this as well.